# date select , openFileDialog equivalent

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to select a date in my winforms app and wish to find something like an openFileDialog, and that is when i click on a button, a calendar shows up and lets me select a date. Is there such a function built in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have it as a Dialog window, but you have a component called [DateTimePicker](http://en.csharp-online.net/DateTimePicker).

If you really need it on a dialog window, you can put this component on it's own form and open that form with `ShowDialog`.

A bit more manual work, but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx).